# Google Cloud BigQuery : Error in Retrieving query result

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, java-8

When I try to fetch count from BigQuery dataset then It's throwing error like :

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;
```

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String datasetName = "users";
    String query =
        " SELECT count(1) "
            + " FROM preprod.users.records"
            + " WHERE section_id = 'sectionId'";
    query(query);
  }

  public static void query(String query) {
    try {
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

      QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.of(query);

      TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);

      results
          .iterateAll()
          .forEach(row -> row.forEach(val -> System.out.printf("%s,", val.toString())));

      System.out.println("Query performed successfully.");
    } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Query not performed \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Version :

```
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.1.4')
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '2.18.2'
```

I've taken reference from the https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Answer (score 1):

I just got solution by adding one more dependency called "gson" library :

```
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.9'
```